# Azure Web Job Console App With Parameter

Tags: schedule, azure-webjobs

I have a console application project and I publish it to Azure Web Jobs.
I want to schedule consoleapp.exe with parameters.
For Example :
First Schedule: consoleapp.exe ImportProducts
Second Schedule: consoleapp.exe OrderTransfer

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Azure Forum.

This is not possible using the portal scheduling features alone. I have done something similar but needed two web jobs that called the .exe (with parameters) by way of a .bat file.

Another alternative is to have a single continuous web job that uses a QueueTrigger. This web job will listen on a queue for requests to "ImportProducts" and "OrderTransfer". But then you'd have to schedule the enqueuing of the requests separately using Azure Scheduler with ActionType of "Storage Queue" or something similar.

Proposed as answer by KloopDogg

Answer (score 1):

To do that, create a scheduled WebJob in the portal.
Then go to your schedule job (under Azure Scheduler), there should be a link to it from the WebJobs screen.
Update the url that is invoked from: `/api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/run` to `/api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/run?arguments={arguments}`

For reference see WebJobs API here - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job

Comment: It is very important to note that this only works if you use POST method.  Your url will look like this https://scm/..../run?arguments=arg1%20arg2%20arg3   (%20 = space)

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach I used:

1. Create an azure webjob. Console app that has Main ( string[] args)
2. Create an azure scheduled task

   - Use HTTP "Post" (read this http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html)
   - Note: remember to put in credentials. My URL looks sommething like this `https://[[UID]]:[[PWD]]@mywebaddress.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/WebJobTest/run?arguments=one`
3. run the scheduled tasks an in the console app you now have access to the arguments.

My log file:

```
[03/16/2016 01:11:35 > 486e37: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[03/16/2016 01:11:35 > 486e37: INFO] Arguments passed = 1
[03/16/2016 01:11:35 > 486e37: INFO] Arguments received = **one**
[03/16/2016 01:11:35 > 486e37: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

Woop!, please note that I haven't tested this with competing schedules and check if any locks occur. I assume not but you know what assume did